# how to get row value with group by clause using subquery in PostgreSQL in Laravel 8?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

This is my table, first I want to get **status_exec** of each **MAX** **(date_sta)** and after that I want to grouped by **status_exec** and get the **COUNT**.

| id_out_sta | status_exec | date_sta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-11-07 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-11-28 |
| 1 | ***5*** | **2021-12-07** |
| 2 | 7 | 2021-04-02 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-12 |
| 2 | ***6*** | **2021-08-07** |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-08-05 |
| 3 | ***5*** | **2021-08-28** |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-03-15 |
| 4 | ***5*** | **2021-04-25** |

The result I would expect should be the following:

| status_exec | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 |

This is my query but it didn't help:

```
SELECT id_out_sta, status_exec , max(date_sta) as max_date_sta
FROM public.status_exe 
join public.order_out on status_exe.id_out_sta = order_out.id_out
group by (id_out_sta);
```

Please any suggestion, **query builder** or **simple query.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common solution for this is `row_number` window function to find the maximum of each group. Using this in a CTE and then aggregating the result:

```
with s as (
    select *,
      Row_Number() over(partition by id_out_sta order by max_date_sta desc) rn
    from t
)
select status_exec, Count(*) "Count"
from s
where rn=1
group by status_exec
```

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c6ded86cce85175d1cd78e0bcf7164e)

Answer (score 0):

Using `DISTINCT ON` followed by a subquery:

```sql
SELECT status_exec, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (status_exec) *
    FROM public.status_exe
    ORDER BY status_exec, max_date_sta DESC
) t
GROUP BY status_exec;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example by using count window function.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_out_sta)
    status_exec,
    count(*) over(partition by status_exec)
  FROM t
  ORDER BY id_out_sta, max_date_sta DESC
) as list
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=971f84cfe85d969329ed977c9ee4d24a)